# Connect to SharePoint subdirectory and get all files

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I'm currently trying to write a little PowerShell script that allows me to get all the files from a certain subdirectory in SharePoint. Afterwards I'll upload them elsewhere, but so far I haven't been able to get them through PS yet.

I pasted the code of the script below. Things go wrong at the try...catch block, suggesting I can't log in. The login + password combo works, I tested it manually in a browser. I think the fault lies at the link, though I don't know how to fix it. I'm inexperienced with SharePoint, but I'm fairly sure the folder lies in a series of directories, filtered with a view. Can anyone decipher the correct link/path?

```
Write-Host "Loading CSOM libraries" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Write-Host "Lib. successfully loaded !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green

$SiteURL = "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/Networks/ModeratorNetwork/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Moderators/Forms/noFolders.aspx#InplviewHash4fbd3088-c2fc-49ef-8865-a032bbb9e671=SortField%3DModeratorID-SortDir%3DDesc"

$PlainPassword = "abc123"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

Write-Host "Trying to reach $SiteURL // Handling ClientContext..." -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("JohnSmith@gmail.com",     $SecurePassword) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($site)
try
{
      $context.ExecuteQuery()
      Write-Host "Connected !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
}
catch
{
      Write-Host "Impossible to reach $SiteURL : bad password ?" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
  return
}

$list = $web.Lists["Moderators"];
$fields = $list.Fields;

$list.Fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path ./blabla.csv;
```

Comment: You have to connect to a site, so https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/Networks/ModeratorNetwork.

Comment: Stop before _layouts.. This URL was copied from the browser and contains (user)navigation info and all kinds of other SharePoint stuff Powershell can't deal with

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense. I was unsure where SharePoint's official URL stops. Can I pass the remaining information from the URL otherwise? With the filtered version, it gets a bunch of folders, but I only need the files within

Comment: Mmhmm, I still get the same error by the way. I pasted the shortened URL in a browser and that redirects me fine, ditto with the username + password. Do either of you happen to see anything else wrong with this?

Comment: Only other thing i see is mixing of cases in $context

Comment: That didn't do the trick. Still, thanks anyway. Wish I had enough points to give you an upvote. I'm going to try SharePoint Online Management Shell, hoping that will do the trick

Comment: In catch statement try to get actual error message. Write now it is giving you same error message as you are showing same message for any error. Check this link to get actual error message in Cache: http://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell